# How to show sidebar in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do I enable sidebar in visual studio 2022, I don't know why, but it's just missing...

[image: Missing sidebar]

Comment: Below is a document about VS information, I believe it can help you understand VS better. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-studio-ide?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to TOOLS –> OPTIONS –> TEXT EDITOR –> ALL LANGUAGES –> SCROLL BARS the scroll bar style can be changed to map mode.

[image]